# When using a USB-C hub for your PC, can you connect multiple inputs and outputs at the same time?

Tags: usb-c, usb-hub

When using a USB-C hub for your PC, can you connect multiple inputs and outputs simultaneously (such as HDMI/ display port out, USB stick, charging your phone and PC charger all connected to the USB-C hub at the same time)?

My understanding was you could but my laptop seems to become slow at times or will completely shut down if I do connect multiple inputs and outputs at the same time to one USB-C hub.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Do you know what generation USB-C port your laptop has and what the hub is designed for?

Comment: Is your USB hub powered by an adaptor or by the laptop itself? You might need a hub with a power adaptor if what you are plugging in is overloading the port on your laptop.

Comment: @pigeonburger USB-C 3.1

Comment: @Mokubai No it is not a powered adaptor. If it is not a powered adaptor, what is the maximum number of devices that can be connected? Power and display out? Or would even this be too much?

Comment: A USB C port can, [in theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_3.0#Power_and_charging), put out 900mA. How many devices that is depends on the kinds of devices and what they are doing. If the dock has its own buffers and display adaptor then that will take some power as well. If you are connecting more than a couple of devices at a time I would really want an independently powered hub. Powering a phone from it will draw power from other devices.

Comment: FWIW my USB hub has no problem doing all of this.